ChatGPT API in Kotlin Android Studio gives me 404 error
Hello i am trying to make an android app with an assistant feature but I am getting 404 error when trying this code although my API key is correct and i have not reached any limit. Any ideas why? According to documentation i have inserted the correct prompts and info about the model and endpoint etc. What am I missing?
EDIT: I purchased a billing plan of $10 and now i get a 400 error, not 404, so that's something. Still can't understand why though.
    package com.serenity.journal

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.ScrollView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import okhttp3.*
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaTypeOrNull
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.IOException

class AIAssistantActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val client = OkHttpClient()
    private val apiKey = "" //My Actual API is put here

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ai_assistant)

        val toolbar: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)

        val chatLayout: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.chat_layout)
        val userInput: EditText = findViewById(R.id.user_input)
        val sendButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.send_button)

        sendButton.setOnClickListener {
            val userMessage = userInput.text.toString()
            if (userMessage.isNotEmpty()) {
                addMessageToChat("User", userMessage)
                userInput.text.clear()
                sendMessageToGPT(userMessage, chatLayout)
            }
        }

        val bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation)
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_home -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("user_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    with(sharedPreferences.edit()) {
                        putBoolean("isPasswordVerified", true)
                        apply()
                    }
                    finish() // End the current activity to return to MainActivity without creating a new instance
                    true
                }
                R.id.navigation_information -> {
                    val intent = Intent(this, InfoActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun addMessageToChat(sender: String, message: String) {
        val chatLayout: LinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.chat_layout)
        val textView = TextView(this)
        textView.text = "$sender: $message"
        chatLayout.addView(textView)

        // Scroll to the bottom when a new message is added
        val chatScrollView: ScrollView = findViewById(R.id.chat_scroll_view)
        chatScrollView.post {
            chatScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN)
        }
    }

    private fun sendMessageToGPT(message: String, chatLayout: LinearLayout, retryCount: Int = 0) {
        val json = JSONObject().apply {
            put("model", "gpt-4")
            put("messages", listOf(mapOf("role" to "user", "content" to message)))
            put("max_tokens", 500)
        }

        val requestBody = RequestBody.create("application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull(), json.toString())
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $apiKey")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.e("GPT-4 Error", "Failed to send message: ${e.message}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val responseBody = response.body?.string()
                    Log.d("GPT-4 Response", responseBody ?: "No response body")
                    val jsonResponse = JSONObject(responseBody ?: "")
                    val reply = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("choices").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("message").getString("content").trim()
                    runOnUiThread {
                        addMessageToChat("AI", reply)
                    }
                } else {
                    if (response.code == 429 && retryCount < 3) {
                        // Retry with exponential backoff
                        val backoffTime = Math.pow(2.0, retryCount.toDouble()).toLong()
                        Log.e("GPT-4 Error", "Rate limit exceeded. Retrying in $backoffTime seconds...")
                        Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                            sendMessageToGPT(message, chatLayout, retryCount + 1)
                        }, backoffTime * 1000)
                    } else {
                        Log.e("GPT-4 Error", "Unsuccessful response: ${response.code}")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: android.view.MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                finish()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}


Nobody? Hasn't anyone ran into this before?
